# How to display featureds page in wordpress home page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-featured-image

I'm trying to show specific pages on the homepage of my theme. The idea is show the page, the featured image and the excerpt. To do this with categories is relatively easy. But with pages, how should I proceed?

Example of page two pages:

http://bit.ly/KO7uLa
http://bit.ly/KwKB2d

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do this follow below steps:

1. Create a [page
   template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) for your
   home page. In this template you can add anything what you needed to
   show on home page.
2. Now Create a page for home from WordPress dashboard and Assign the
   template you created now for that page.
3. Go to settings-> Reading-> Click Front page displays as static page
   and select the page we created now for Home page.

**Codes  for your template page**

Put the below code in your template file to display the title and excerpt and featured image of a particular page.

```
<?php
$post_id = 1;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);
echo "<h2>" . $title . "</h2>";
echo "<p>" . $queried_post->post_excerpt . "</p>";
?>
```

Make sure to change the post_id.

Hope this will help you.

Cheers !!!

Comment: Nice! I was googling and found this article:
http://monstertut.com/2012/04/display-particular-specific-post-page-in-wordpress/

What do you think of this method?

Thanks!

Comment: Thats a nice tutorial. Go ahead.